# Select list option isnt being set with Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Select list:

```
<select id="Outcome#1" class="result" name="Outcome#@1">
                            <option value="x">Select</option>
                            <option value="4">Good</option>
                            <option value="3">Adequate</option>
                            <option value="0">Not Applicable</option>
                        </select>
```

Jquery

```
$("#Outcome#1").val("4");
```

The above select list is being dynamically created from a DB call, and the javascript is also being created on the fly and the val being populated If one exists in the DB.

However, in the above example, the dropdown isn't being set to have Option 4(Good) set to Selected.

I'm under the impression that the above bit of JQuery should do this quite happily.

Also tried: (and failed)

```
$("#Outcome1[value='4']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you cannot have a `#` in an ID

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss The HTML5 spec is considerably less restrictive. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @AnthodyGrist Yes, and also (at present) considerably less implimented especially in some browsers :) and of course in some libraries such as jQuery (by default)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` in the `id` attribute is a meta-character, so will need to be escaped as part of your jQuery selector:

```
$('#Outcome\\#1').val("4");
```

This is explained at the top of the [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) API page.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I realised when I submitted it!

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is actually looking for an element with an `id` attribute of both `Outcome` and `1` - which is impossible. You need to escape that `#` in the selector itself, try this:

```
$("#Outcome\\#1").val("4");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the hashsign

```
$("#Outcome\\#1").val("4");
```